# jQuery Dialog makes scrollbars appear in main content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

[This test of jQuery dialog](http://plungjan.name/test/testjquerydialog.html) makes the scrollbars appear in the main content when the dialog is opened. When I touch the dialog resize, the scrollbars go away. Is it the way I defined the dialog or too much content?
Click the [!] in the top right corner to see this.
Platform: XPsp3, browsers: FF3.6.3, IE8, Safari 5
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See here for a couple different ways to approach: [Opening a Modal Dialog shows a horizontal scroll bar](https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/3623)

Quick CSS fix:

```
.ui-widget-overlay {
   position: fixed;  /* <---------- */
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

Or call this when you open your dialog:

```
open: function(event, ui){
    $('body').css('overflow-x', 'hidden');
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I have not tested it, but it looks like what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Why has the dialog container div got the style property `position` set to `relative`, this should be `absolute` going by the [jQuery UI demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

When I change it to `absolute` in firebug the scrolbar problem resovles itself.

Comment: erm... whoever made it relative... I did not make anything relative on purpose... If you view source you will not find any relative, only in the generated source.

Comment: So what to do if I do not want to change the jQuery.css?